# In two diffrent form how to get the input value from other form and submit with one button?

Tags: javascript, php, web, phpmyadmin

This below is my code:

```
  <form action="test.php" name="updateform">
  //user input id
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" placeholder="">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update" id="update" name="update">
  </form>

  <form action="test.php" name="searchform">
  //user input name
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" id="search" name="usearch">
  </form>

   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE movie SET name=? WHERE id = ?");
```

The search button is at searchform, and update button is at updateform.
When I want to update the name where the id and it fail. How to update the name with the id from searchform when update button is pressed?

Comment: Put id and name in the same form if you want them both to update with one button.

Comment: Because I need seperate the ID to searchform, so I can do with search function by searching through ID, and I want to update  the NAME from updateform form using the ID from searchform.

Comment: You are using both the name and the id for the "search"... So you can put both buttons in the one form and take the appropriate action. You could, on the other hand, save the id in a session and use it from there when you perform a search...

Comment: Is this id a member id or something? Why would I be able to change it?

Comment: ID was auto increment when I insert data to database, When I need to update I search by ID, this is the movie ID.

Comment: Alright, I get it at well buy using session, and you said just no need display.